# Extra semicolon in catch block

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

I am reviewing various coding styles of GitHub authors to learn and get inspiration and this one is puzzling me. One author is consistently using an extra semicolon within locally handled catch block.

```
catch (SpecificException e) {
;
}
```

when wanting to ignore exceptions locally, I would just write

```
catch (SpecificException e) {}
```

As there is no difference between those two, so why one would use the extra semicolon?

Comment: doesn't change nothing..

Comment: Not knowing the author or their intentions I can only hazard a guess, but it would be that they are using it as a "This page intentionally left blank" notice.

Comment: In general, you should never have a totally empty catch block -- there should at least be a println or some such.  But a bare `;` can be placed anywhere a "statement" is legal.

Comment: Changed the example to `SpecificException` as one pointed out that generic `Exception` shall be propagated up. However this was not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's personal preference, the author might use that so an empty catch block is more noticeable.

Comment: Later I did find out that this was exactly the case, he was having a script which was doping this on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`;` is an empty statement, so doesn't matter how many of those you would add.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add an extra `;` to denote empty catch block. The way you used should be preferred, and it is more clear. The extra `;` is simply absurd.

Having said that, both the styles of `catch` block should be avoided. You should not have an empty catch block. That does more harm than good. You should at least have your catch block as:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Apart from that, you should try not to have a catch block to catch all kinds of `Exception`s. You should create catch blocks for specific types of exception, so that you can handle them in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why have a catch block to do nothing with it. That being said, if I for whatever reason have an empty catch block I do it as `catch (Exception) {}`
This just changes is so that it still recognizes the empty catch block, but doesn't give me warnings that 'e' is initialized but never referenced.

Answer (score 0):

It could be personal preference as if you check the java doc for **Calendar.getInstance()** method you will notice that theya are using same coding style preference.

```
public static Calendar getInstance(TimeZone arg, Locale arg0) {
    return createCalendar(arg, arg0);
}

private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone arg, Locale arg0) {
    CalendarProvider arg1 = LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(CalendarProvider.class, arg0)
            .getCalendarProvider();
    if (arg1 != null) {
        try {
            return arg1.getInstance(arg, arg0);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException arg6) {
            ;
        }
    }
```